# How to register a variable from within the class definition in the header file c++

Tags: c++, macros

I'm working on some code where the getters and setters of a class are created using a macro. Something like

```
class MyClass : MyStruct
{
    MEMBER(m_member1);
    MEMBER(m_member2);
    MEMBER(m_member3);
    MEMBER(m_member4);
    MEMBER(m_member5);
}
```

where MEMBER is a macro that creates a setter and getter for the members which are defined in the MyStructBase.

I want to modify the MEMBER macro to add some kind of registration for each member. So that in addition to creating setters and getters, the MEMBER macro also does something like calling m_myRegistry.register(Member1) for each member. Essentially being able to register each member of the class without having to rewrite the code (we have a very large number of this MyClass classes so would save a lot of work if I only have to modify the macro and no the constructors of the classes).

So, my question is, is there a way to call a function from within the class definition to solve this problem? I'm thinking it might be possible by declaring a static class that's template specialised on the actual member, but I can't think how to do it.

Edit: I have been asked to show the macro used. It's quite complex and I'm not sure if my company would be particularly happy for me to post their code on stack overflow, so I'm going to post a simplified version of it:

```
 #define MEMBER(membername)
    // some boost magic to typdef membername##traits::Type to the type of membername
    ...
    //
    membername##traits::Type get##membername()
    {
        return membername;
    }
    void set##membername(const membername##traits& a)
    {
         membername = a;
    }
```

So what I want is to modify the macro to do something like:

```
 #define MEMBER(membername)
    // some boost magic to typdef membername##traits::Type to the type of membername
    ...
    //
    membername##traits::Type get##membername()
    {
        return membername;
    }
    void set##membername(const membername##traits& a)
    {
         membername = a;
    }

    m_objectRegistry.register(membername);
```

Comment: I assume some data *type* is involved in that macro. It would likely be considerably more informative to include what that macro does *currently*. Don't just tell us about it; *show it*. A concrete example of what it currently does (a simple `MyStruct` base, a simple derivation, etc), and what you *want* added to it, would add considerable volume to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can define another member, which registers the original member (only works in C++11):

```
struct MyRegistration
{
    template <typename T>
    MyRegistration(ObjectRegistry& objectRegistry, T member)
        {objectRegistry.register(member);}
};

...

#define MEMBER(membername) \
    /* some boost magic ... */ \
    MyRegistration<membername##traits::Type> \
        dummy##membername{m_objectRegistry, membername};
```

This increases the number of members in your class, so may be inconvenient.

The declaration of the new dummy member also mentions the parameters to its constructor.

This code registers the member of each instance (object) of your class; I am not sure this is what you want. If you want to register the member just once, `static` might work.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing except that it won't work from within the class declaration will it? Wouldn't this need to be called from within the constructor of the class?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could initialise inline like that in C++11. Is there any way to do it in C++03?

Comment: Maybe it's possible in C++03, but certainly not in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Macro is just a piece of code which will be replaced in the called places before the compilation. So just try to write all the codes inside the macro. Anyway if you want to call a function inside the macro then it is better to create the function as Global instead of creating a static class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer, would you be able to give an example to show me what you mean? Maybe modify my macro that I have added to the question with an example?

Comment: What he means is that you can do something like:  
 
`#define MEMBER(membername) \
    membername##traits::Type get##membername()  {  return membername;  } \
    void set##membername(const membername##traits& a) {  membername = a;  } `  

and then whenever you you type MEMBER(varname) then the compiler will replace the MEMBER macro with whatever it defines which in this case will be the code that you provided in your example.

Comment: @Hjorthenify I understand how macros work. But the code in my example doesn't compile as it is invalid c++. I was wondering what the correct c++ code to do what I want would be!

Comment: I'm not expert in #define, but I've used the provided code before. Not for dynamic types though. I just assumed that it would work with traits::Type as it was the method you provided for getting the data type. What error is the compiler generating?

Comment: I haven't tried it, I just know that m_objectRegistry.register(membername); in the class definition doesn't mean anything

Comment: @dan debugging the macros are not much tricky ... in the place where you are going to call the macro, write the whole macro code, compile and run. If everything working fine, then move the piece of code to the top, assign the code to a macro and call the macro instead of that piece of code. This is very good debugging way to encounter issues in macro...

Comment: I'm sorry but this is very frustrating. I think you are misunderstanding the whole point of the question I am asking. Please read the answer below to understand what I am looking for.